Parse array of mixed types including strings with Jackson
I have to parse an API returning an array containing mixed objects and strings. Jackson parser does throw an exception, since I do not know how to structurize the Kotlin classes. There is several information on the market about Polymorphism using the JsonTypeInfo annotation, but sadly I could not find anyone dealing with mixed objects and strings in an array. Is there a simple solution?
Maybe one hint: Jackson parser is set and cannot be changed.
val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
    .registerModules(JavaTimeModule())
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

data class Polymorphism(
    val list: List<TestClass>
)
data class TestClass(
    val anything: String?,
    val subTest1: SubTest1?
)
data class SubTest1(
    val myString: String
)

val testJson = """
    {
      "list": [
        "Hello World",
        {
            "subTest1": {
                "myString": "Teststring"
            }
        },
        {
            "subTest1": {
                "myString": "Another Teststring"
            }
        }
      ] 
    }
""".trimIndent()

val poly = mapper.readValue(testJson, Polymorphism::class.java)

In example above, a Jackson MismatchedInputException is thrown.

What makes this difficult is having a String at the same level as an object in the array.  You will need to create a custom deserializer on the Polymorphism.list (which you can do with the @JsonDeserialize annotation, so you do not need to alter the Jackson parser.

Yes, using a custom serializer is the most practical solution! Put annotation @JsonDeserialize(using = TestSerializer::class) over TestClass with following implementation, solves the issue above.
object TestSerializer : JsonDeserializer<TestClass>() {
    override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext): TestClass {
        val node = parser.readValueAsTree<JsonNode>()

        val retVal = when(node.nodeType) {
            JsonNodeType.OBJECT -> when(node.fieldNames().next()) {
                "subTest1" ->  TestClass(subTest1 = parser.codec.treeToValue(node["subTest1"], SubTest1::class.java))
                else -> TestClass("Unknown field")
            }
            JsonNodeType.STRING -> TestClass(text = node.asText())
            else -> TestClass("Unknown Node")
        }

        return retVal
    }
}

